# Trying to change CSS on New-Post page (WP-admin)

Tags: css, wordpress

I’m inside the New Post page on WP-Admin, where you can create a new post.
At the right column, there’s the category selector, in which you select the category for that new post.

I have something like 15 categories, and therefore the category box is showing with a scrolling bar. Since I need to automate some post creation, I need all the categories to be visible right away, without having to scroll.

So I found the css file that manages the height of the category box (it’s inside /wp-admin/css/edit.css and //wp-admin/css/edit-rtl.css) and there I changed the CSS files to allow a bigger height by default on that box.

However when I open the new post page, it still shows the small box in categories, and when I see the CSS rule, the change I made is not visible. It’s like the CSS is cached or something. I already made sure that my browser is not caching it.

The problem I think it’s because the CSS rules are not pulled directly from CSS files, but from this file:

http://www.website.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load%5B%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,buttons,media-views,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menu&load%5B%5D=s,widgets,site-icon,l10n,wp-auth-check&ver=4.7

That file seems to go and gather the CSS information from some place (which I assumed was the CSS files in the wp-admin/css/ folder, in which I could find the exact same CSS rules that were applied to the category box) but for some reason, it’s not retreiving the updated CSS file. Or something else is happening (Server side caching the PHP response and therefore retreiving all the time the old response?)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend tampering with core admin files, as any changes you make could be lost from a WordPress update.

The proper way to do it is through a custom function added to your theme or child-theme **`functions.php`** file:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_css');

function custom_admin_css() {
  echo '<style>
     /* remove scrollbar from categories panel */
     .categorydiv div.tabs-panel { max-height: none !important; }
  </style>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another options that will allow you to have CSS for individual pages is to use this [OH header/footer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oh-add-script-header-footer/) plugin. Once you install the plugin you can then add your CSS in the header textarea of the pages admin. Just make sure you enclose your CSS within a `<style></style>` tag.